# How can community members respectfully protest closed questions and get constructive feedback without further down votes?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

I've been getting a little more frustrated with the SE network lately as some questions are closed or down voted without further explanation.

I'm assuming that the regular course of action for protesting would be to use Meta, however, whenever I see a meta protest, that user gets further down votes and gets slammed by the same mods that closed their original question.

What is a good way to "respectfully" protest their closed questions, receive constructive feedback, and ultimately STILL find the answer they were originally looking for?

---

As an aside, not to be confused with the original content of this question, I'm asking because I have a closed question that I'd hope to protest on meta.programmers. My question [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/133782/github-workflow-for-solo-developer) was closed as a duplicate. However, my question is "what is the best approach" where the supposed duplicate is "are there benefits".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The best way is to just explain why your question shouldn't have been closed.  If your reasons are wrong you're going to get downvoted.  Meta rep doesn't really mean much, so I wouldn't worry too much about it.  If you're right (and I think you have a case with the post you linked to) then it should get reopened by the community or by a moderator.

---

I just did a search here on Meta for ["question should not have been closed"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=question%20should%20not%20have%20been%20closed) and found a lot of positive examples (among the negative ones, of course) that you can look at.  Just state your case as to why you think your question doesn't fit the close reason given.  If you can do that without going off on a rant, you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks Bill. I've posted and we'll see how it goes.